# Deploying spring boot app using Heroku Maven Plugin

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I would like to deploy my spring-boot app to Heroku.
I got it working just fine using `heroku-cli-deploy` plugin with the command:

```
heroku deploy:jar "my-app.jar" --app {my-app-name}
```

But now I would like to use `heroku-maven-plugin` to do this deployment.
I have my pom.xml build section:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${artifact-name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
                <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
                <includes>
                    <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                </includes>
                <jdkVersion>${java.version}</jdkVersion>
                <processTypes>
                    <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar
                        ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</web>
                </processTypes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I'm using `mvn clean heroku:deploy` to deploy the app. The deployment fails showing the following error:

```
Error: -jar requires jar file specification
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This change made it work:

```
   <processTypes>
       <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar ./target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</web>
   </processTypes>
```